# A proxy method for a generator

Tags: python, generator

I have a generator method `next_item(data)`

I call it in a loop:

```
for count, item in enumerate(next_item(data)):
    # do something here
```

But now I want to extend my program - to fork the `next_item` method into two methods based on the input.

So the next_item() would look like this:

```
if ...: # some condition here
  yield(next1(data)) # or return(next1(data)) ??
else:
  yield(next2(data))
```

But return does not work `("SyntaxError: 'return' with argument inside generator")` and `yield` apparently leads into the item being a generator instead of an item of this generator.

So I will have to refactor the calling script but I was wondering whether there is a way how to write such a proxy generator.

Comment: _"But return does not work"_. Did you replace the first `yield` with a return? Or did you replace both? Could you post the actual code that produced that error?

Comment: It's not clear to me what you are trying to do. Are `next1` and `next2` regular functions, or generators themselves? If you want to proxy a generator, you just do it: `if ...: yield next1(data).next()` etc... or return the generator's output i.e. `if ...: return next1(data)`...

Comment: Kevin: I replaced only one, yes, that was the problem. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your error message, it sounds like you tried something like:

```
if ...: # some condition here
  return (next1(data))
else:
  yield (next2(data))
```

Python won't accept a function that both yields and returns. You need to change *both* yields into returns if you want it to work.

Here is an example of a function that chooses between two generators:

```
def squares():
    i = 0
    while True:
        yield i * i
        i += 1

def evens():
    i = 0
    while True:
        yield i*2
        i += 1

def next_item(switch):
    if switch == 0:
        return squares()
    else:
        return evens()

print "printing squares..."
for idx, item in enumerate(next_item(0)):
    print idx, item
    if idx > 10: break

print "printing evens..."
for idx, item in enumerate(next_item(1)):
    print idx, item
    if idx > 10: break
```

Result:

```
printing squares...
0 0
1 1
2 4
3 9
4 16
5 25
6 36
7 49
8 64
9 81
10 100
11 121
printing evens...
0 0
1 2
2 4
3 6
4 8
5 10
6 12
7 14
8 16
9 18
10 20
11 22
```

---

If you like, you could make `next_item` a generator as well:

```
def next_item(switch):
    if switch == 0:
        for item in squares(): yield item
    else:
        for item in evens(): yield item
```

Or possibly:

```
def next_item(switch):
    for item in squares() if switch == 0 else evens():
        yield item
```

And if you're using 3.X, you can use `yield from`:

```
def next_item(switch):
    yield from squares() if switch == 0 else evens()
```

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I did - I replaced only one of the two yields by return. I did not realize from the error that this was the problem. Thanks!